# How do I open several files at once in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Often when I start emacs I open the same set of files. How can I make it so that I can quickly select several files from a directory and open them?

Comment: See related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1110487

Answer (score 14):

You could try setting up a [fileset](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Filesets.html#Filesets) in Emacs to accomplish this .

Comment: +1 I did not know about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

When you open emacs you can run `dired`. This will allow you to *mark* several files and open them at once. Not the best method, just putting it out there.

[Dired Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html) |
[Marking files with Dired](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Marks-vs-Flags.html#Marks-vs-Flags)

Comment: You can't do this with `dired`, (unmodified.) However `dired+` can, or use Trey Jackson's *defun* :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1110487/311660

Answer (score 6):

Yet another alternative is to just use a file glob (`C-x C-f ~/foo/*.c RET`, or `proj/*/*.[ch]`, etc)

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't know you could do that! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the desktop commands, you can save your desktop into a file, say at the top of your project and then use desktop-change-dir to that project and it will load the files.

Have a look at the documentation on saving sessions. http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html#Saving-Emacs-Sessions

Answer (score 2):

**This is a think-outside-the-box solution:**

I use [ENSO launcher](http://www.humanized.com/enso) on my windows and am more than satisfied with it.

- select the files you want to open in explorer or total-commander or anywhere
- simply press ENSO button and type `open with emacs`
- and presto :)

I know it is not an emacs solution, but it is a very helpful productivity tool.

Comment: Probably want `emacsclient` instead of `emacs` so that the file will open in the Emacs you already have running. You know, the one you started after your last reboot and will be open until your next reboot?